# Is ok to deactivate a user account using GET http verb?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, http

Im stuck with a simple but tricky task that im developing on `ASP.NET MVC 5` web app.

I have a **UserManager** view wich i need to add a button to deactivate the account of the current logged user. So i have two options:

1) Create a input tag an hold the click event making a post using ajax:

```
<input type="button" id="deleteUser" value="Delete Account"/>

 <script>
 $('#deleteUser').click(function() {
        $.post("@Url.Action("DeleteUser")",function() {
            window.href.location = "@Url.Action("Home","Site")";
        } );
    });
 </script>
```

On controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
  [Authorize]
  public ActionResult DeleteUser()
  {
      //return json
  }
```

2) Create a **href** and make a **GET** pointing to the **DeleteUser** action.

IMO these two options are correct, but the right thing to do is delete a user using the `DELETE` Http Verb, right? Since `HTML5` doesnt support it, how to deal with it? In the options above, i prefer to use a href, because i can make a feedback easily based on the logic that i have, and i dont need to make a script for it.

Comment: I would recommend using a POST request rather than GET. You generally don't want non-cacheable actions for a GET method.

Comment: A third option: Wrap the button in a `<form />` that gets POSTed-- no JS required

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker but shloud i use post even if im not posting data to the server?

Comment: @ggui: I think it's fine.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker since i know, i just can make a direct DELETE Verb using XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: @ggui: That seems like a good way to go too